# How is tail-call optimization in FPLs implemented at the assembly level?

Tags: optimization, assembly, lisp, tail-recursion, ml

How do LISPs or MLs implement tail-call optimization?

Comment: Did you do *any* research on this before asking?

Comment: [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Implementation_methods) a place to start looking.

Comment: You can read about it in the sicp book as well, [5.4.2  Sequence Evaluation and Tail Recursion](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html#%_toc_%_sec_5.4.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't speak on the exact implementation details different compilers/interpreters, however generally speaking tail-call optimization operates like this:

Normally a function call involves something like this:

1. Allocate stack space for the return
2. Push your current instruction pointer onto the stack
3. Allocate stack space for the function parameters and set them appropriately
4. Call your function
5. To return it sets it's return space appropriately, pops off the instruction pointer it should be returning to and jumps to it

However when a function is in tail position, which pretty much means you are returning the result of the function you are about to call, you can be tricky and do

1. Re-use the stack space allocated for your own return value as the stack space allocated for the return value of the function you are about to call
2. Re-use the instruction pointer you should be returning to as the instruction pointer that the function you are about to call will use
3. Free your own parameters stack space
4. Allocate space for the parameters and set appropriately
5. Set the value of your parameters
6. Call your function
7. When it returns, it will be returning directly to your caller.

Note that #1 and #2 don't actually involve any work, #3 can be tricky or simple depending on your implementation, and 4-7 don't involve anything special from the function you are calling. Also note that all of this results in a 0 stack growth with respect to your call stack, so this allows for infinte recursion and generally speeding things up a little.

Also note that this kind of optimization can be applied not only to directly recursive functions, but co-recursive functions and in fact all calls that are in tail position.

Answer (score 3):

It's CPU-architecture and/or operating system dependent what kind of functions can be tail-call optimized. That's because *calling conventions* (for passing function arguments and/or transferring control between functions) differ between CPUs and/or operating systems. It usually boils down to whether anything passed in the tail call must come from the stack or not. Take, for example, a function like:

```
void do_a_tailcall(char *message)
{
    printf("Doing a tailcall here; you said: %s\n", message);
}
```

If you compile this, even with high optimization (`-O8 -fomit-frame-pointer`), on 32bit x86 (Linux), you get:

```
do_a_tailcall:
        subl    $12, %esp
        movl    16(%esp), %eax
        movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        call    printf
        addl    $12, %esp
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "Doing a tailcall here; you said: %s\n"
```

i.e. a *classical* function, with stackframe setup/teardown (`subl $12, %esp` / `addl $12, %esp`) and an explicit `ret` from the function.

In 64bit x86 (Linux), this looks like:

```
do_a_tailcall:
        movq    %rdi, %rsi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        jmp     printf
.LC0:
        .string "Doing a tailcall here; you said: %s\n"
```

so it got tail-optimized.

On an entirely different type of CPU architecture (SPARC), this looks like (I've left the compiler's comment in):

```
.L16:
        .ascii  "Doing a tailcall here; you said: %s\n\000"
!
! SUBROUTINE do_a_tailcall
!
.global do_a_tailcall
do_a_tailcall:
         sethi   %hi(.L16),%o5
         or      %g0,%o0,%o1
         add     %o5,%lo(.L16),%o0
         or      %g0,%o7,%g1
         call    printf  ! params =  %o0 %o1     ! Result =      ! (tail call)
         or      %g0,%g1,%o7
```

Yet another one ... ARM (Linux EABI):

```
.LC0:
        .ascii  "Doing a tailcall here; you said: %s\012\000"
do_a_tailcall:
        @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
        @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
        @ link register save eliminated.
        mov     r1, r0
        movw    r0, #:lower16:.LC0
        movt    r0, #:upper16:.LC0
        b       printf
```

The differences here are the way arguments are passed, and control is transferred:

- 32bit x86 (`stdcall` / `cdecl` type calling) passes args on the stack, and hence the potential for tail call optimization is very limited - apart from specific cornercases, it's only likely to happen for exact argument passthrough or when tail calling functions that take no arguments at all.
- 64bit x86 (UNIX `x86_64` style, but not too different on Win64) passes a certain number of arguments in registers, and that leaves the compiler considerably more freedom on what can be called without having to pass anything on the stack. Control transfer via `jmp` simply makes the tail-called function *inherit* the stack - including the topmost value, which would be the return address into the original caller of our `do_a_tailcall`.
- SPARC not only passes *function arguments* in registers, but also *return addresses* (it uses a *link register*, `%o7`). So while you *transfer control* via `call`, that doesn't actually force a new stackframe since all it does is to set both link register and program counter ... to undo the former via another odd feature of SPARC, the so-called *delay slot instruction* (the `or %g0,%g1,%o7` - sparc-ish for `mov %g1,%o7` - is executed *after* the `call` but *before* the target of the `call` is reached). The above code is created from an old compiler rev ... and not as optimized as theoretically could be...
- ARM is similar to SPARC as it uses a link register, which tail-recursive functions just pass unmodified/untouched to the tail-call. It's also similar to x86 by using `b` (branch) on tail recursion instead of the "call" equivalent (`bl`, branch-and-link).

In all architectures where at least some argument passing can happen in registers, tail call optimization can be applied by the compiler on a large variety of functions.